# how does step function in aws scale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

experimenting with aws step functions ( sample code below), if this is hooked up to a certain event, say s3 object notification , for each object created will it spin up a new state machine/step function like a lambda instance.

```
data "template_file" "stepFunc" {
  template = file("step-func-definition.json")
}

resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine" {
   name = "a-step-function"
   role_arn = aws_iam_role.step_function_role.arn
   definition = data.template_file.stepFunc.rendered
}
```

Comment: "for each object created will it spin up a new state machine/step function like a lambda instance." Was that supposed to be a question? If so, the answer is "yes".

Comment: @MarkB - thanks. yes that was the question.